# Get Short Month

Tags: c#, .net, date

How can I get the short month (Jan, Feb, Mar...) from a date. See my code below:

```
x.wk_endingdate.AddDays(-6).ToShortDateString()
```

also tried

```
x.wk_endingdate.AddDays(-5).Month.ToString()
```

Sample Expected result:

If wk_endingdate is equal to 1/25/2018, result should be Jan.

Comment: Format date with MMM

Comment: When i use something like x.wk_endingdate.AddDays(-6).ToShortDateString("MMM"), this will only display MMM.

Comment: No use to string or string format functions

Comment: With same result for toString("MMM")

Comment: Adjusted the code to this: x.wk_endingdate.AddDays(-5).ToString("MMM") and display the expected result. Thanks!

Comment: `ToShortDateString("MMM")` shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 3):

Use format `"MMM"`

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("M"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Result

```
February 1
02
Feb
February
```